# Different C# Output Between Release and Debug

Tags: c#, debugging, release, language-lawyer

I've a little C# program here that produces different output between the Debug and Release versions. The empty output from the Release version is, I think, consistent with the C# Language Specification. This program should not produce output, yet the Debug version does.

I've run both the Release and Debug versions from the command line (outside the VS environment) and get the same inconsistent output. I've decompiled the Debug version (using ILDASM) and then re-compiled it with ILASM. When I do this, the newly compiled program behaves just like the Release version. I can only imagine that when I de-compile and then re-compile something is being left out but I've not been able to determine what's different.

Regarding the EXE file size: Both the Release and Debug versions produced by VS have the same file size: 5,120 bytes. When I de-compile and re-compile, both versions again have the same, but smaller file size: 3,072.

The program is quite small and I've looked at the IL in Reflector and I can't see anything that would cause a difference in output.

Does anyone have a (hopefully detailed) explanation of exactly why there is a difference?

Please note that I'm not *trying* to make the Debug and Release versions consistent, necessarily, I want to understand why they are not.

Recall what I said above -- both the Debug and Release versions produce different output *even when run from the command line*. If you tell me the runtime is doing some kind of optimization for the Release version but not for the Debug version then there must be something embedded in the Debug/Release version assemblies that tell the runtime to turn on/off optimizations.  What is that embedded "something" and why does it not carry over when using ILDASM/ILASM?

Here's the code:

```
using System;

class Test {
    static int value = 0;
    static int a = Initialize("Assigning a");
    static int b = Initialize("Assigning b");
    static String name = "Fred";
    static int c = Initialize("Assigning c");

    static int Initialize(String mssg) {
        ++value;
        Console.WriteLine("In Initialize() :: {0}, name={1}, returning {2}", mssg, name, value);
        return value;
    } // Initialize()

    static void Main() {
    } // Main()
} // class Test
```

And here is the output from the Visual Studio generated Debug version:

```
In Initialize() :: Assigning a, name=, returning 1
In Initialize() :: Assigning b, name=, returning 2
In Initialize() :: Assigning c, name=Fred, returning 3
```

Running the release version generates no output.

Comment: Most probably, in release mode, Test class in not loaded since there is no reference to it. Try by adding `Console.WriteLine(Test.name);` to your main method.

Comment: I would recommend putting a `Console.WriteLine("In Main");` to show that main is actually getting called. (I just tried you still get the different output, however if you do more, for example `Console.WriteLine("In Main() :: {0}", name);`, then debug and release start behaving the same)

Comment: paging mr skeet, mr skeet please come to the SO desk

Comment: If you want, I found [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2007/10/19/how-to-see-the-assembly-code-generated-by-the-jit-using-visual-studio.aspx) showing how to disable debugging optimizations so you can still see the differing behavior in the debugger (and if you check the box for "Enable address-level ebugging" you can see the assembly code from the Disassemby window). I know what is happening (the JITed code does not call the other static methods), but I don't know ***why*** it is happening so I am not going to post an answer just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

The static class initializer is not called until its needed. Clearly the debug and release versions decided differently about when its needed. IN particular my guess is that the release build optimized the main out entirely and so never loaded the class. It seems to have decided that since main does nothing it can optimize everything out - in this case it seems to be a bad decision

Comment: *"IN particular my guess is that the release build optimized the main out entirely and so never loaded the class."* That is not the case, put `Console.WriteLine("In Main()");` in main and you still get the same behavior but it will print "In Main()"

Answer (score 2):

Turning optimizations on (release mode) affects the IL generated, as well as the behaviour of the JITter.

You are probably seeing the initialization of the unused variables being eliminated by the JITter.

This explains the ILDASM/ILASM behaviour, and the fact that there's no significant difference in the IL.

I suspect this behaviour is controlled by the value of the [CorDebugJITCompilerFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232499.aspx) flag somewhere in the CLR header.. See *[Does C# compiler /optimize command line option affect JITter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003672/does-c-sharp-compiler-optimize-command-line-option-affect-jitter)*

Comment: If you put in `Console.WriteLine("In Main()");` that will print without the static functions being called. so Main is not being eliminated entirely.

Comment: So I see. I suppose just the initialization of the unused variables is eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

After more research, I found the answer I was looking for (thanks to Blogbeard for pointing me in the right direction).

It turns out that when you compile for Debug, the generated assembly is, by default, decorated with a DebuggableAttribute whose "Debugging Mode" is

```
DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default
```

It is apparently this combination of flags that seem to turn off JIT optimization, resulting in the output I saw in the Debug version of the program. The Release version of the program has a different "Debugging Mode", allowing JIT optimization to proceed.

Of course, if you manually set the DebuggableAttribute in the AssemblyInfo (as I did during testing) for the Debug build, you can override the default behavior.

I'm sure there are some CLR/JIT Lawyers out there who can explain in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually use the variables a, b, or c in the application (inside Main) anywhere so I'm assuming they're being optimized away. When I run that code in LinqPad with optimizations off, it shows the output you describe and with optimizations on, it shows nothing other than Main() executing. If I update the code in Main() to reference one of those variables, the output is consistent with the optimizations off build.