# A Static Initializer that Shouldn't be Running

Tags: c#, static, initializer

Earlier I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636243/different-c-sharp-output-between-release-and-debug/29638332#29638332) regarding static initializers and differing outputs between the Debug and Release versions of the same code. I determined the Release version produced different output (actually it produced *no* output) from the Debug build because a `DebuggableAttribute` setting allowed the JIT optimizer to eliminate the output in the Release version.

The more I think about this though, the more it bugs me. Before I go further, let me show the code from my original posting and the output produced in a Debug build:

```
 using System;

 class Test {
    static int value = 0;
    static int a = Initialize("Assigning a");
    static int b = Initialize("Assigning b");
    static String name = "Fred";
    static int c = Initialize("Assigning c");

    static int Initialize(String mssg) {
       ++value;
       Console.WriteLine("In Initialize() :: {0}, name={1}, returning {2}", mssg, name, value);
       return value;
    } // Initialize()

    static void Main() {
    }// Main()
 } // class Test
```

The output from this code (when run with a Debug build) is this:

```
In Initialize() :: Assigning a, name=, returning 1
In Initialize() :: Assigning b, name=, returning 2
In Initialize() :: Assigning c, name=Fred, returning 3
```

I understand perfectly well that the JITter is able to optimize away the output and I understand why it would do so, so I'm not asking anyone to address the differences between Debug and Release builds.

What's bugging me is **why** *any* output should appear in the first place. The class has no static c'tor (which would have forced static initializers to run), there are no references to the static fields from outside the class and the class is never instantiated. The point I'm making is that the output produced by this code should never have been produced in the first place, not even by the Debug build, at least from my understanding of the Language Spec.

I've been poring over pieces of the C# spec and I can't find anything that says static initializers should run for the code shown below, regardless of whether it's compiled for Debug or Release.

Can anyone explain why this code should ever produce output and what part of the language spec applies?

Thanks.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the `Main` method and run the code with the debugger attached. When it breaks, what values do you expect the five fields to have? Try it in Debug and Release modes. Also note that all the initializers (assignments written at the declarations) are technically moved to a static type initializer by the C# compiler. So even if there is no static constructor in the C# code, the CLR sees it as a static method `.cctor`. However, the CLR is free to run or not run it (no field is referred). Also in the Release mode, try a version where you write out `name` in `Main`.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour is defined as implementation-dependent:

> [10.4.5.1 Static field initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758.aspx)
>
> If a static constructor (Section 10.11) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. **Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class.**

I would guess that it makes debugging easier to initialize them early.

Comment: Your quote would correspond to Section 10.5.5.1 of the current spec. In my code example, there is no static c'tor, so that doesn't apply. Additionally, there are no uses of static fields either. In other words, none of the static fields are referenced, so there is no need to run the static initializers.

Comment: There is no *need*, but there is no requirement *not* to run them. Any time "prior to the first use of a static field" is allowed. Since there are no uses of a static field, any time at all is ok.